# MYSQL: Way to match n-1 conditions out of n in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I am dealing with a set of complex generated SQL queries with several LEFT JOINS and somewhere between three and two dozen conditions in the WHERE clause. So let's say we have `n` conditions in the WHERE clause. Now I'd like to allow any match that almost does it, too - that is any one that matches `n-1`of the conditions. I'd also like to know which one failed but I can determined that in PHP later on so it's not a priority.

My question: Do I have to verbosely put all possible combinations of the conditions into the WHERE clause using `()` braces and `OR` or is there possibly a clever and elegant solution to such a situation that I'm not yet aware of?

**EDIT:** Let's ignore the joins and let's conceive a single table:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE colA='something' AND colB='something else' AND colC='5' AND colD<colE AND colF='1'
```

So that's 5 conditions, we'd like to match any 4 of them and know which one failed. In a way that is extensible so that it does not matter if we are dealing with 5 or 25 conditions.

This is the clumsy thing I'd like to avoid:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE (colB='something else' AND colC='5' AND colD<colE AND colF='1') OR (colA='something' AND colC='5' AND colD<colE AND colF='1') OR (colA='something' AND colB='something else' AND colD<colE AND colF='1') OR (colA='something' AND colB='something else' AND colC='5' AND colF='1') OR (colA='something' AND colB='something else' AND colC='5' AND colD<colE) OR (colA='something' AND colB='something else' AND colC='5' AND colD<colE AND colF='1')
```

Comment: post your table definitions, sample data, and current query

Comment: @amdixon let's keep it abstracted. Posting an SQL query with a thousand+ characters and 50 tables doesn't help.

Comment: it is possible, but you need to provide a simple use case with same behaviour

Comment: @amdixon Do you think the above will do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use conditional aggregation for this:

```
SELECT id -- primary key fields
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN colA='something' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS condition1
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN colB='something' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS condition2
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN colC='something' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS condition3
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN colA='something' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
     + SUM(CASE WHEN colB='something' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
     + SUM(CASE WHEN colC='something' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
     >= 2
```

You can add the conditional aggregate fields into your `SELECT` if you want to track which ones succeed or fail, and put it in a subquery to join back on `id` to get the full record detail.

In `MySQL` you can shortcut the syntax slightly with just `SUM(colA = 'something')` instead of the `CASE` expressions.

Comment: that looks a lot like "a clever and elegant solution to such a situation that I was not yet aware of" could you add the thing amdixon is suggesting to the answer?

Comment: This is so neat! I really learned something here. Thank you. This makes a nice pre-christmas present.